# Display loading progress modal doesn't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, vb.net

I need progress loading message after the SQL select finish executing. I've got a code from the internet but the modal doesn't hide after the loading finish. I need this kind of concept. Is there any code that can help me to make progress loading message after i select a query.. my problem is when i select too much data in SQL there is an eager loading that why i need progress message show that the process of selecting a data is ongoing/rendering from the database.

This is the code from internet now i'm trying to do but there is a bug the modal doesn't hide after loading finish.

```
       <style type="text/css">
    .modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:Black;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: White;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I think this assumes that the page will be redirected.  It doesn't contain a callback.

Comment: The code are running even there is no vb.net code the function run after the submit button

Comment: @pcalkins what callbacks that im going to do

Comment: What is the form's action set to?  If it's not set to anything at all, then you are not posting the form.  You have 2 options.  1) Add an action which calls something on the server-side that processes the form and then re-directs.  2) Add code in your javascript to post the form and retrieve a callback.  Then update the HTML accordingly.... which would also involve hiding the loading div.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `live` [is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/live/) use 'on' instead.

Next, what happens in your code, is that you append your modal to the body and show it with jquery's `show` *on a submission of a form*.

You can notice how there is no code whatsoever that removes/hides your modal. You have a multitude of options to do that. You will either need to **obtain** your modal when removing or hiding it, or **save it in a variable** inside of the `ShowProgress` function:

- Remove your modal from the document.
- Hide your modal using jquery's `hide()`.
- Add or remove CSS classes or styles.

Now, there is a third issue that might be happening: you have no idea when the form is done submitting. Which well... it never is unless you changed something else with some other code. A form submit, by default will do a post request to it's destination. So normally, the user will be redirected and the need for hiding the modal is non-existent.

*I don't think it is valuable to show any code examples on how to do this here, as it doesn't seem that you have tried to understand the code you took from the internet. I do believe that this answer is sufficient enough to point you to the right google searchss*

Comment: why should i remove the CSS classes? Can you give some sample code to do what are you going to say. And i'm sorry because I am not good in jquery.